# Вопрос по воссозданию функции memmove

Tags: c

Нашел интересный способ воссоздания библиотечной функции memmove.

*(The  memmove()  function  copies  n  bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas may overlap: copying takes place as though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src or dest, and the bytes are then copied from the temporary array to dest)*

Но никак не могу понять - как работает простое с виду условие предотвращения наложения (overlap) **if (dest > src)**. Оно сравнивает длину строки dest и src или же номер адреса памяти dest и src?
Если предположить что величину строки - то попробуем симулировать ситуацию с наложением, вместо mdest задав в качестве параметра msrc+2, что должно вызвать ситуацию наложения одной строки на другую при копировании. Вот так: ft_memmove((msrc+2), msrc, 2);

По логике msrc+2 короче msrc и наше условие **if (dest > src)** выполняться не должно, но оно все равно почему-то выполняется предотвращая наложение. Как это работает?

```
void    *ft_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    size_t            i;
    char            j;
    unsigned char    *d;
    unsigned char    *s;

    i = 0;
    j = 1;
    d = (unsigned char *)dest;
    s = (unsigned char *)src;
    if (!dest && !src)
        return (NULL);
    if (dest > src)
    {
        j = -1;
        d += n - 1;
        s += n - 1;
    }
    while (i < n)
    {
        *d = *s;
        d += j;
        s += j;
        i++;
    }
    return (dest);
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{    
  char msrc[] = "abcde";
  char mdest[4];  
  ft_memmove(mdest, msrc, 2); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Там в цикле указатели увеличиваются на j. Оно может быть +1 или -1, и цикл соответственно или с конца, или с начала. Когда целевой адрес налагается на исходный в конце, нужно идти от конца массива, потому что если идти от начала, то первые же байты наложатся на исходный массив, а если с конца, то сначала будет копироваться на свободное место, потом на то место, откуда уже данные были скопированы. Если накладывается на начало, то цикл просто от начала массива, чтобы сразу перенести начальные байты, которые потом затрутся в процессе копирования.

Comment: Если коротко - в первую очередь нужно копировать данные оттуда, где они будут затерты. Если накладывается на конец, то начинать с конца, когда на начало - то с начала.

Comment: А что сравнивает выражение if (dest > src) - длину строк?

Comment: Адреса. dest - это место куда копируется, src - откуда. Если dest > src, значит "куда" находится после адреса "откуда", значит накладывается на конец исходного массива, значит копировать нужно начинать с конца.

Comment: Точнее не точно накладывается, но может наложиться. Но накладывается или нет фактически - не нужно проверять, нужно просто проверить с какой стороны может наложиться.

Comment: Условие `if (dest > src)` сравнивает адрес приемника с адресом источника. (Причём тут вообще длины строк, если кол-во копируемых байт задаётся третьим параметром функции?) Это условие не предотвращает наложение приемника и источника, но в зависимости от их взаимного расположения в памяти выбирает  способ копирования от начала к концу или от конца к началу. Если приемник и источник не пересекаются, то направление копирования не важно. А если пересекаются, то правильный выбор направления позволяет избежать затирания источника до завершения копирования.

Comment: P.S. Строго говоря, поведение приведённой функции не определено. 1) Указатели `dest` и `src` можно сравнивать операторами больше/меньше только если они указывают на элементы одного и того же массива или на гипотетический элемент за последним. 2) Если `j` отрицательно, то на последней итерации цикла `while (i < n)` указатели `d` и/или `s` могут выйти за начало массива. Разыменования нет, но для UB достаточно простого выхода указателей. P.P.S. Если тип `char` беззнаковый, то присвоение `[char] j = -1` ошибочно. В условии `if (!dest && !src) return (NULL);`, вероятно, нужен оператор `||`.

Comment: @wololo, я правильно понимаю что `memmove` не стандартном C написать нельзя эффективно, так как нельзя проверить перекрытие диапазонов? Остаётся только побайтовое копирование без оптимизаций.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не нужно проверять перекрытие, нужно проверить с какой стороны перекрытие может быть, а потом копировать можно хоть 64-битными интами, остаток добить байтами. Ну, точнее, чтобы 64-битными интами эффективно копировать, нужно копировать с выровненного адреса на выровненный адрес, но это в принципе решаемо на Си.

Comment: @insolor, нельзя нам смотреть "с какой стороны перекрытие может быть". Про это и вопрос.

Comment: @insolor, нельзя сравнивать (<, >, <=, >=) указатели если не известно что это указатели в один и тот же массив.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy с точки зрения стандарта - может и нельзя, с точки зрения практики - можно. Результат ничем не будет отличаться от аналогичного кода на ассемблере.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, было бы слишком смело с моей стороны утверждать, что чего-нибудь нельзя сделать эффективно на стандартном C :) И тем не менее идей, как сделать эффективный переносимый `memmove` на стандартном C у меня нет. Проверить перекрытие диапазонов можно оператором `==`. Сравниваем каждый байт `dest` на совпадение с началом `src`, а потом наоборот, но это неэффективно. Можно указатели привести к `uintptr_t`, а потом сравнивать целые. Но даже если `dest` и `src` указывают в один массив, и `dest < src`, то не гарантируется `(uintptr_t)dest < (uintptr_t)src`.

Comment: Функция отображения между указателями и целыми определяется реализацией. Да и тип `uintptr_t` опциональный. Хотя возможно, что на практике это самый переносимый способ среди не вызывающих UB. @insolor `с точки зрения практики - можно` Может и так... Но смотря на примеры [наподобие такого](https://godbolt.org/z/zPbfe5Ye6), становится как-то неспокойно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, imho http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/memmove.c достаточно эффективная реализация